# Expected value of a discrete random variable: rolling a dice and a coin

Tags: probability

I have this question:
Find the expected value of rolling a dice and a coin, if you get a head you add 1 to the dice outcome, and if you get a tail you multiply by 2 to the dice outcome.

I tried to do it but I couldn't realize which is my X random variable to be able to calculate its probability function.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please read this post on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/947379).

Comment: Rolling a dice and **flipping** a coin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways to solve this question. I will state some hints only here but hope you could eventually fill the gaps.

**Method 1.** Let $X$ be the number you get. Then we need to determine the range of $X$. You can consider as follows:

Suppose you roll a one. Then $X=1+1=2$ if you get a head and $X=1\cdot 2=2$ if you get a tail. Since rolling a die and flipping a coin are independent, each of them has probability $(1/6)\cdot(1/2)=1/12$.

You can analyze the remaining cases analogously and list the distribution of $X$. After that you can use the definition to find the expectation.

——————

**Method 2.** This method is somewhat tricky, so you can ignore it temporarily if you find it too hard. Let $Y$ be the number you get from the die and $Z$ be the result of the flip.

Then $Y$ follows a uniform distribution from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and $Z$ follows a uniform distribution from $\{H,T\}$. Also observe that
$$X=\begin{cases} Y+1, & Z=H; \\ 2Y & Z=T \end{cases}, $$
where $X$ is the total number you get. Then
\begin{align}
E(X\mid Z=T)&=E(2Y)=2E(Y)=2(3.5)=7, \\
E(X\mid Z=H)&=E(Y+1)=E(Y)+1=3.5+1=4.5. 
\end{align}
As a result,
$$E(X)=E(E(X\mid Z))=7(0.5)+4.5(0.5)=5.75.$$

Comment: Thank you! You really enlightened me.
Just one question, in the Method 1, if I roll a one, shouldn't it be X=1×2=2 if I got a tail, as it is stated in the problem?

Comment: @AHexe Hi AHexe, thanks for pointing this out! I somehow misread the question, but I have my solutions updated now.

Comment: Thank you again!